# When to use 'i' vs. 'str[i]'?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

why does using 'i' in the if statement return different results than using 'str[i]'?

```
function ExOh(str) { 
  xCount = 0;
  oCount = 0;
  for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    if (str[i]=='x') {
      xCount++;
    } else if (str[i]=='o') {
      oCount++;
    }
  }
  if (xCount==oCount) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(ExOh("xox"));
```

Comment: Why do you think? `i` contains a number, `str[i]` contains a character. Note also that the final if/else structure can be replaced with `return xCount==oCount;`.

Comment: Because `str[i]` is not the same as `i`

Comment: Which `if` statement? There are three in your code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` returns the current value of the same in the for loop: `for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++)`

And, `str[i]` returns the character in the string `str` at the `i'th` position.

So, although the value of `i` is the same inside the `if` or `for` loop, the actual values of `i` and `str[i]` will be different.

*Readup:*

- [`for` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
- [`array` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: `str` isn't an array.

Comment: @nnnnnn How do you know? OP hasnt specified it in the code/question.

Comment: The question shows that the function is called with a string value. (Obviously it *could* be called with an array or array-like object, but given what it does and the argument name "str" it seems intended for strings.)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `i` refers to the *index* of a character in the string `str`, and when you use `str[i]` you are accessing the character of `str` at index `i`. For example, take the following string:

```
var str = "My string";
```

The string `str` has 9 characters, and each index, from 0 to 8, will refer to a specific character within it. Thus, `str[0] = "M"`, `str[1] = "y"`, etc. Here, 0 and 1 are indexes, while `"M"` and `"y"` are characters at such indexes.

Answer (score 0):

why does using 'i' in the if statement return different results than using 'str[i]'?

I in this case is an integer indicating the place (index) within an array.  Where is str[i] is the item within that place.

Comment: `str` isn't an array.

Comment: @nnnnnn if it is intended to be a string as you suggested - why then does he not use string functions (namely charAt())?  I believe it's intended to be an array of characters.   Subtle javascript quark.

Comment: @Rahul Desai,This taking up an hour of my day to find there makes little difference.  It is NOT a string 'literal'.  Javascript covernts it to a string object once it's called passed to the function, ExOh("val") <-- String,  function ExOh(str) <--'str' String Object

Comment: Using square bracket array-style syntax to access the characters of a string is supported in all modern browsers; you only need to use `.charAt()` to support older browsers (old IE). Given the usage shown in the question (a string is passed to the function) and the name of the variable it is clearly intended to be a string, though of course it will also work on an array or array-like object.

Answer (score 0):

`i` refers to the *position* or index of a character (beginning at `0`), so in this case `i` refers to the index of a character in the string. It will return a number.

`str[i]` refers to the exact character of that string, not its position or index, so it will return a non-number, unless that character in the string happens to be a number.